# how to escape php code in echo with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

how can i escape this : `var tab_mois_nb_match = <?php ".json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match)." ;?> ;`

I have an code error, but the arrays are generate with sussess in the conle.log, it's totally crazy.

```
 foreach($tab_bases2 as $key => $univers){              
            $tab_nb_match_par_user = users_nb_match($univers);
            $tab_mois_nb_match = mois_nb_match($univers);

            echo "<div id='".$univers."' ></div>";
            echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'> 
                    var tab_mois_nb_match = <?php ".json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match)." ;?> ;
                    var line3 = [];tab_date = [];
                    for(var v in tab_mois_nb_match){
                        line3.push([v,Number(tab_mois_nb_match[v])]);
                        tab_date.push(v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]);
                    }
                    console.log(tab_mois_nb_match);
                  </script>";
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing inline PHP with a PHP command (echo).

When you are echoing a string, you do it just like normal, this means you can mix literal strings (the js you are manually typing) and the output of functions (like a json in this case):

```
echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'> 
                var tab_mois_nb_match = ".json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match)." ;
                var line3 = [];tab_date = [];
                for(var v in tab_mois_nb_match){
                    line3.push([v,Number(tab_mois_nb_match[v])]);
                    tab_date.push(v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]);
                }
                console.log(tab_mois_nb_match);
              </script>";
```

A string is a string.

Edit:
On that note though, I should add, if you need something to be evaluated PRIOR to being inserted into a string, just drop some brackets around it.

```
echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'> 
                var tab_mois_nb_match = ".(json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match)+4)." ;
                var line3 = [];tab_date = [];
                for(var v in tab_mois_nb_match){
                    line3.push([v,Number(tab_mois_nb_match[v])]);
                    tab_date.push(v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]);
                }
                console.log(tab_mois_nb_match);
              </script>";
```

Okay, so +4 is a bad example, but say for example, you needed the output of a function inserted into another function... brackets are the ones that do the trick.

Lastly, not ALL functions will work like this. Sometimes, you just have to save the output of a function into a variable and then insert the variable into the string.

Comment: thanks man , I tried  this var tab_mois_nb_match = ' ' '".json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match)."  ' ; and I was lost

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare php inside php.

You can write your code in two ways:

First Method:

```
 foreach($tab_bases2 as $key => $univers){              
        $tab_nb_match_par_user = users_nb_match($univers);
        $tab_mois_nb_match = mois_nb_match($univers);

        echo "<div id='".$univers."' ></div>";
?>


<script type='text/JavaScript'> 
                var tab_mois_nb_match = <?php json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match) ;?> ;
                var line3 = [];tab_date = [];
                for(var v in tab_mois_nb_match){
                    line3.push([v,Number(tab_mois_nb_match[v])]);
                    tab_date.push(v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]);
                }
                console.log(tab_mois_nb_match);
              </script>

<?php                  
     }
?>
```

Second Method

```
foreach($tab_bases2 as $key => $univers){              
        $tab_nb_match_par_user = users_nb_match($univers);
        $tab_mois_nb_match = mois_nb_match($univers);

        echo "<div id='".$univers."' ></div>";
        echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'> 
                var tab_mois_nb_match = ".json_encode($tab_mois_nb_match)."  ;
                var line3 = [];tab_date = [];
                for(var v in tab_mois_nb_match){
                    line3.push([v,Number(tab_mois_nb_match[v])]);
                    tab_date.push(v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3]);
                }
                console.log(tab_mois_nb_match);
              </script>";
     }
```